# OSX mac is disconnected how do I boot in?

Tags: macos

When I turn on the computer, the screen is grey. 
After some time, I can only see a folder with a question mark.
<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work if I restart.
What else can I try?

Comment: I think you should try [method 2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127070/90381)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few more things, but it's hard to say how useful they'll be; the blinking-question-folder is a symptom of HDD failure, OS corruption, File System corruption, and more.

1. Try Single-User:  Boot holding `Command-S`.  This attempts to boot your OS at a very low level, so some kinds of operating system corruption won't interfere with single user mode.  This isn't very useful unless you're comfortable in a command-line only shell.  `fsck -fy` may help resolve something.
2. Try diagnostics:  Boot holding `D` (maybe `option-D` or `command-D` could do something different; worth a shot if just D doesn't do it for you).  This will check some quick things and let you know if something in your hardware is very broken.  It's not conclusive, but it could rule out other things.
3. Try targeted:  Boot holding `T`.  This will turn your mac into a very large external drive.  You can plug it into another computer with firewire or thunderbolt plugs/cables.  This will allow you to browse the file system.  If your HDD is empty, that explains why it gives the blinking folder:  It can't find any operating system.
4. Try Internet Recovery:  Boot holding `Command-Option-R`.  This is sort of a last resort; it will let you reinstall OS X from scratch, even without a properly working onboard recovery partition.  This may wipe your drive, depending on the level of file system damage you already have, and it won't work at all if your hard-disk-drive has physically broken.  Internet recovery will also let you pull up a terminal and browse your HDD, run disk repairs in Disk Utility, and run some other command-line utilities.

I concede that these options are perhaps more than the casual user is ready for, but that's why services like the AppleStore and GeekSquad exist.  They already have this knowledge, as well as some useful tools like Apple Certified Diagnostics programs.